# List of map as inout of custom Hive UD

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions

I'm created a UDF and expect List<MAP<STRING,STRING>> argument. It works fine in unit test. However when I use it in hql. I cannot get any value of the map by key. it's always null.
However log shows every key has non-null value. don't know why.

error message：

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: service_type cannot be
> null:{value=告訴%{name}為甚麼你需要更改訂單,
> source_hash=d793db7dee0d1941600c29427383bce8c03ebd84,
> source_locale=en, source_updated_at=1501377418000, content_type=PLAIN,
> service_type=HUMAN}

```html
 // UDF code:

public class MusselContentUDF extends GenericUDF {
  private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MusselContentUDF.class);

  private ListObjectInspector listObjectInspector;
  private MapObjectInspector mapObjectInspector;

  @Override
  public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments) throws UDFArgumentException {
    ObjectInspector a = arguments[0];
    if (!(a instanceof ListObjectInspector)) {
      throw new UDFArgumentException("first argument must be a list / array");
    }
    this.listObjectInspector = (ListObjectInspector) a;
    if (!(listObjectInspector.getListElementObjectInspector() instanceof MapObjectInspector)) {
      throw new UDFArgumentException("element must be map type");
    }
    this.mapObjectInspector =
        (MapObjectInspector) (listObjectInspector.getListElementObjectInspector());

    return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaByteArrayObjectInspector;
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
    List<MusselContentUnit> contentUnits =
        this.listObjectInspector
            .getList(arguments[0].get())
            .stream()
            .map(
                e -> {
                  Map<?, ?> map = mapObjectInspector.getMap(e);
                  if (map.get("service_type") == null) {
                    LOG.error("service_type cannot be null:" + map);
                    throw new RuntimeException("service_type cannot be null:" + map);
                  }
                  if (map.get("value") == null) {
                    LOG.error("value cannot be null:" + map);
                    throw new RuntimeException("value cannot be null:" + map);
                  }
                  if (map.get("source_hash") == null) {
                    LOG.error("source_hash cannot be null:" + map);
                    throw new RuntimeException("source_hash cannot be null:" + map);
                  }
                  if (map.get("source_locale") == null) {
                    LOG.error("source_locale cannot be null:" + map);
                    throw new RuntimeException("source_locale cannot be null:" + map);
                  }
                  if (map.get("source_updated_at") == null) {
                    LOG.error("source_updated_at cannot be null:" + map);
                    throw new RuntimeException("source_updated_at cannot be null:" + map);
                  }

                  return MusselContentUnit.builder()
                      .serviceType((String) map.get("service_type"))
                      .value((String) map.get("value"))
                      .sourceContentDescriptor(
                          SourceContentDescriptor.builder()
                              .sourceHash((String) map.get("source_hash"))
                              .sourceLocale((String) map.get("source_locale"))
                              .sourceUpdatedAt(Long.valueOf((String) map.get("source_updated_at")))
                              .contentType((String) map.get("content_type"))
                              .build())
                      .build();
                })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    try {
      return ThriftCodec.serialize(MusselContent.builder().units(contentUnits).build(), true);
    } catch (TException e) {
      throw new HiveException("Cannot parse idl request content");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String getDisplayString(String[] children) {
    return "MusselContentUDF(" + children[0] + ")";
  }
}
```

```html
hql code:

q4 AS (
SELECT MUSSEL_PRIMARY_KEY(publisher_name, model, field_name, shard_num) AS primary_key
    ,CONCAT(field_name, '.', locale) AS secondary_key
    ,MAP(
        'service_type', service_type,
        'value', value,
        'source_hash', source_hash,
        'source_locale', source_locale,
        'source_updated_at', source_updated_at,
        'content_type', content_type
     ) AS content_unit
FROM q3
)
,
q5 AS (
SELECT primary_key
    ,secondary_key
    ,COLLECT_LIST(content_unit) AS content_units
FROM q4
GROUP BY primary_key, secondary_key
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The map keys may not be strings when you get the map from mapObjectInspector. Currently I see two possible ways how to solve the problem:

1. Try to use `getMapValueElement(Object data, Object key)` method to get the map value
2. To work out keys and values ObjectInspectors, e.g.,

   ```
   protected transient PrimitiveObjectInspector keyOI;
   protected transient PrimitiveObjectInspector valueOI; 

   keyOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) this.mapObjectInspector.getMapKeyObjectInspector();
   valueOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) this.mapObjectInspector.getMapValueObjectInspector();
   ```

then use `getPrimitiveJavaObject` to get the Java object and cast it to `String`, this way you can cast `Map<?, ?> map` to `Map<String, String>`, and then use `new_map.get("service_type")`.

Unit tests are not realy helpful, I would suggest you to use [HiveRunner](https://github.com/klarna/HiveRunner) instead